# Elastic beanstalk environment health keeps going to warning/ degrading while ignore 4xx is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a elastic beanstalk environment which often gives a 404 error as response or throws it when reading from a SQS queue. But even thought I have the following enabled:
[image: Ignore 4xx enabled]

I still get the following errors within elastic beanstalk:
[image: Environment health issues]

Which setting am I missing to configure this correctly?